# Percorrer array verificando props existentes e retornar um novo array, com um objeto para cada prop existente

Tags: javascript, array, typescript, react-native

Possuo um array de objetos em que cada objeto é uma transação com quantia, data e tipo:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "amount": 2000,
    "date": "August 2022",
    "totalExpensesByMonth": 0,
    "totalRevenuesByMonth": 0,
    "type": "income",
  },
  Object {
    "amount": 1000,
    "date": "August 2022",
    "totalExpensesByMonth": 0,
    "totalRevenuesByMonth": 0,
    "type": "income",
  },
  Object {
    "amount": 1000,
    "date": "August 2022",
    "totalExpensesByMonth": 0,
    "totalRevenuesByMonth": 0,
    "type": "outcome",
  },
  Object {
    "amount": 1000,
    "date": "August 2022",
    "totalExpensesByMonth": 0,
    "totalRevenuesByMonth": 0,
    "type": "outcome",
  },
  Object {
    "amount": 1000,
    "date": "July 2022",
    "totalExpensesByMonth": 0,
    "totalRevenuesByMonth": 0,
    "type": "income",
  },
  Object {
    "amount": 1000,
    "date": "July 2022",
    "totalExpensesByMonth": 0,
    "totalRevenuesByMonth": 0,
    "type": "income",
  },
  Object {
    "amount": 1000,
    "date": "July 2022",
    "totalExpensesByMonth": 0,
    "totalRevenuesByMonth": 0,
    "type": "outcome",
  },
]
```

Gostaria de percorrer este array verificando quais as datas existem e retornar um novo array, com um objeto para cada data existente, com a soma das quantias de acordo com o tipo da transação (caso o tipo seja "income", somar na prop "totalRevenuesByMonth", caso o tipo seja "outcome", somar na prop "totalExpensesByMonth").

Utilizei o método reduce para acumular as datas existentes e um switch para verificar os tipos das transações e somar a quantia da transação nas props "totalRevenuesByMonth" ou "totalExpensesByMonth", mas o valor acumulado final destas props não está como eu queria:

```
const totalsByMonths = transactionsByMonths.reduce((acc: any, current: any) => {
        if (!acc[current.date]) {
          acc[current.date] = {
            ...current
          }
          return acc
        }

        switch (current.type) {
          case 'income':
            acc[current.date].totalRevenuesByMonth = acc[current.date].amount + current.amount
            break;
          case 'outcome':
            acc[current.date].totalExpensesByMonth = acc[current.date].amount + current.amount
            break;
        }

        return acc
      }, [])

      const newList: any = Object.values(totalsByMonths);
      console.log(newList);
```

A saída deste código acima é:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "amount": 2000,
    "date": "August 2022",
    "totalExpensesByMonth": 3000,
    "totalRevenuesByMonth": 3000,
    "type": "income",
  },
  Object {
    "amount": 1000,
    "date": "July 2022",
    "totalExpensesByMonth": 2000,
    "totalRevenuesByMonth": 2000,
    "type": "income",
  },
]
```

O "totalExpensesByMonth" de "August 2022" deveria ser 2000, mas está 3000, já o "totalExpensesByMonth" de "July 2022" deveria ser 1000, mas está 2000.

Comment: Além da pergunta sugerida acima no box azul, ver também [aqui](/q/496269/112052) e [aqui](/q/441261/112052), pode ajudar a ver outras alternativas que não precisem de `reduce` (e que na minha opinião, são bem mais simples). Enfim, o problema é que vc está somando o `amount`, e não o total que vc quer atualizar. Dentro do `case 'income'` deveria ser `acc[current.date].totalRevenuesByMonth += current.amount` e no `case 'outcome'` deveria ser `acc[current.date].totalExpensesByMonth += current.amount;`

Comment: Ah, e dentro do `if (!acc[current.date])` vc também precisará fazer o `switch`, senão o objeto começará com o respectivo total zerado. Ou não ter esse `return` - aliás, eu acho `reduce` um exagero para este caso, veja como um loop simples já resolve: https://ideone.com/A8ZFdC